# OrientDB - Find related items of a vertex

Tags: orientdb, traversal

We are building a system that will audit searches of a user (as well as other actions by the user). We will be tracking data such as User1 searched for Term1. There is an edge called 'searched' between a User and a Term vertex. What we are trying to find is some related information like users that searched for Term1 also searched for these terms (Term2, Term3, etc) and possibly some other related information between users and terms like "you may know these users". I am guessing a traversal is needed, however what I'm wondering is if depth of a traversal matters and will tell us the data we want. If we go the traversal route how deep do we set before we lose actual relevance?

So far this is what we pieced together but we aren't entirely sure if it is the correct approach.

```
SELECT $depth, * FROM (TRAVERSE * FROM (SELECT FROM Searched where q = 'al') STRATEGY BREADTH_FIRST ) WHERE @class in ['Term']
```

**Update**: what I ended up going with so far was the following query. It will tell me what other users searched for and a count of how many times. So I sort by how close a vertex is and how many times it was searched for. I feel this should hopefully provide a fairly good sample of what other users are searching for that also searched for that term.

```
SELECT $depth, q, in().size() AS count  FROM (TRAVERSE * FROM (select from Term where q.toLowerCase() = 'aluminum') STRATEGY BREADTH_FIRST) WHERE @class = 'Term' AND $depth <> 0 ORDER BY $depth ASC, count DESC
```

Comment: Hi, which version are you using? Thanks

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi we are using 2.2.0

Comment: ok, could you explain better, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: My main interest for now is getting the users who searched for X also searchrd for Y, and then you may know these users based on them also searching for similar things multiple times.